# Dynamic Named Range based on Another Cell Value

Tags: excel

I have two columns, col A contains an ID number from 1 to 9999 and column B contains a list of names. I would like to create a dynamic named range for column B where the associated ID value is between 999 and 9000. Normally I would use the OFFSET function to define the named range. Is it possible to expand the functionality to exclude records in col B based on the value in col A?

I would like to avoid filtering, vba, pivot tables or manipulating the raw data if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give example desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with only 1 limitation that your filter on ID column should result in continuous values, e.g. the filter can be ID >= 5 and/or ID<=1000

If this is acceptable, solution would be:

Along with ID (column A) & Name column (column B), create a third column (column C), e.g Name2 where

```
Name2 = =IF(AND($A2>=start_val,$A2<=end_val),B2,"")

ID  Name    Name2
1   A   
2   B   
3   C   C
4   D   D
5   E   E
6   F   F
7   G   G
8   H   
9   I   
10  J
```

create two other name ranges for your filter

```
start_val   3
end_val     7
```

finally, create a namedrange with formula:

```
xyz = OFFSET(Name2,MATCH(start_val,ID,0)-1,,1+MATCH(end_val,ID,0)-MATCH(start_val,ID,0),)
```